# Condition by value of label -> css on div

Tags: jquery, css

i want to hide (change the background to none) in case that a label value = 'XXXX'

My html is like:

```
<dl id="checkout-payment-method-load">
<dt> 
<span class="no-display">
<input id="p_method_si_NAME1" value="si_NAME1" type="radio" name="payment[method]" checked="checked">
</span>
 <label for="p_method_si_NAME1">
NAME1
</label>
</dt>
<dd id="container_payment_method_si_NAME1" class="payment-method">
<ul class="form-list" id="payment_form_si_NAME1">
<li>
</li>
</ul>
</dd>
</dl>
```

And i try like this jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       if($('.checkout-payment-method-load').sibling('dt').sibling('label').html() == 'Name1'){
        $('.checkout-payment-method-load').sibling('dt').css("background","none");
       }


    });
```

The thing is that i have a background for the normal status, but if i have label value = 'XXXX' i want to display out.

How could do?

Comment: Is it auto-generated? If not, it's better to add a class to those labels and put it to CSS. Generally, contents shouldn't determine appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

1. `checkout-payment-method-load` is id of element and not class. Thus you need to use id selector instead of class selector.
2. You need to find the label element as it is child element and not siblings of `#checkout-payment-method-load`:

   ```
    if($('#checkout-payment-method-load').find('label').html() == 'Name1'){
        $('#checkout-payment-method-load').find('dt').css("background","none");
    }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for tell me to use find method!
Works fine!

Answer (score -1):

if your if clause is correct then u should just change the `.css("background","none");` to `.css("display","none");`.

I mean for making something invisible you should do this

```
$('# any tag ').css("display","none"); ==> will be InVisible
$('# any tag ').css("display","block"); ==> will be Visible
```

Full

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   if($('.checkout-payment-method-load').sibling('dt').sibling('label').html() == 'Name1'){
    $('.checkout-payment-method-load').sibling('dt').css("display","none");
   }


});
```